# Как при сериализации добавить в уже существующий xml файл один объект из коллекции?

Tags: c#, serialize, сериализация

Доброго времени суток!
У меня есть коллекция, которую я получил при десереализации. Когда я добавляю в коллекцию новый объект и опять эту коллекцию серелизую, приходится обрабатывать опять всю коллекцию, что очень долго в моём случае, так как большие объёмы информации. Есть ли способ так сказать досериализовать один объект в существующий файл.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не уверен, что это возможно.

Думаю, вам стоит вручную (ну там в цикле, например) сериализовать каждый объект класса. Когда нужно добавить ещё один - просто добавляете его в конец.

Comment: Значит, у вас неправильно организовано хранение информации.

Сериализация как таковая подразумевает полную сериализацию, невозможно «досериализировать» что-либо. Храните свои объекты по отдельности или сериализуйте список вручную.

Comment: Вообще для таких целей используют БД, например SQLite

Comment: @beliy26rus: ну, база данных — это оверкилл на мой вкус, так как вам придётся заморачиваться с SQL или подключать OR/M, что довольно трудоёмко, а нужно вам всего-то сериализовать один дополнительный элемент.

Comment: Я уже сделал. решение было на много проще чем мне казалось. Я просто создал XmlDocument подключился к готовой xml'ке при помощи Load и добавил в неё всё необходимое через новые XmlElement.

Comment: @Maksisyan: Хм. Если данных у вас реально много, не слишком ли много памяти занимает `XmlDocument`?